# "Working" tri-state MOSFET Push-Pull leakage

Tags: led, mosfet, capacitance, push-pull, tri-state

I have been working for a while on this design, where there are 9 push-pulls that should drive a charliplexed LED array. Therefore the circuit must be able to provide three states, namely: HIGH(12V), LOW(GND), and HIGH-Z.

As you can see in the attached image, each MOSFET is individually controlled by two GPIOS. For now, I am doing this with an Arduino MEGA, but later I will do it on my own board with a Ugs=3.3V and keeping the 12V.

Datasheets: [DMC2400UV](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMC2400UV.pdf), [DMN2990UD](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMN2990UDJ.pdf)

[image]

At first instance the circuit fulfilled its purpose, however, there are three effects that I would like to fix for the next batch and I would like to ask you what would be a good approach.

1. On some occasions when turning on an LED, there is a leakage that makes other LEDs turn on.

My theory is that an NMOS or a PMOS is not completely OFF (HIGH-Z is not achieved), this may be due to a weak pull-up/down, as I consider 47k to be a somewhat high value. It may also be due to a MOSFET that got damaged during reflow or simply it arrived defective.

2. The fastest on/off frequency is 1ms, which in theory should be totally ok for these transistors (~20ns worst case), however, at all times I could perceive the flickering of the LEDs.

Here I enter unknown territory and excuse my ignorance, but could this be due to a malfunction of the input capacitance of the NMOS and PMOS, which are 37.1pF and 46.1pF respectively, and thus, the lack of a series resistor to the GPIO that [limits the gate charge current](http://becomingmaker.com/arduino-pwm-mosfet-gate-resistor/)?

3. Regarding the "safety clearances", although the maximum conditions in which the MOSFETs will work is 12V@30mA, I consider that the maximum Uds of the DMC2400UV is somewhat close (20V), that is why I am thinking of changing it for the [DMG1029SV](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/115/DMG1029SV-1524973.pdf) but I don't know if I am overlooking some feature that makes it incompatible to my implementation. Also the DMN2990 for the [DMN2004VK](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/115/ds30865-89465.pdf) only because rework on SOT-963 has been hell due my hand shakiness.

Comment: You’ve got your hypotheses, so put it to the test and get some evidence. If you think there is leakage, then measure it.once you start measuring the nodes, the numbers should lead to a conclusion.

Comment: *and thus, the lack of a series resistor to the GPIO that limits the gate charge current?* That should not be any issue, gate resistors are usually only needed for larger MOSFETs (higher current rating, much higher gate capacitance). *I consider that the maximum Uds of the DMC2400UV is somewhat close (20V)* **I don't**, I think using a 20 V MOSFET at 12 V supply is **perfectly fine**. No need to use a different MOSFET.

Comment: I think your best bet is to **measure all voltages** while the drivers are in High-Z mode, are all voltages as expected? My feeling is that your design is fine and that there's an error on the PCB.

Comment: *Some* mcu suffers from the lack of resistors since they have extremely anemic GPIO drive. However that wouldn't be the effect. I'd check with a scope the gate signals, charliplexing is *very* critical on the order you drive the pins to avoid spurious flashes (first put all back to tristate, then drive to the right value). And most important, *do not* pass in shoot-thru! Also check there is no IRQ slowing down your manouvers

Comment: A 20V FET is quite adequate for a 12V load if you don't expect transients. Also you may consider to use some miniature bridge driver, it will do the same thing with a lot less components.

Comment: @Kartman I know that I have my hypotheses formulated, however, due to Corona regulations, the time I have as a student to use the lab is extremely limited, so I would like to have different points of view beforehand to get the best out of it once I am in the lab and thus avoid realizing later that I might have made a very elementary measurement that I overlooked. I think that's completely reasonable.

Comment: hey @Bimpelrekkie will do! thank you for reaffirming that the circuit looks good.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio puh.. a lot of info, thanks! With respect to the Charlie drive, I have the code already quite polished, there is no way two MOSFET will be active at the same time, and the T_on and T_off time is also considered to avoid any shoot-thru. However, I didn't get what you mean with IRQ and how it will be slowing the maneuver time, could you please elaborate on that?  Also, if not too much to ask, I already considered the Full and half-Bridge, but maybe I didn't found the correct one, could you also please give me a starting point/recommendation?

Comment: If you are driving the GPIO and an IRQ occurs your GPIO drive will be delayed, easy. Put a scope on the GPIOs to check the timings and when you are sure attack the issues on the powertrain